# Build a cron job running first weekday of every 3 months

Tags: r, ubuntu, cron

I want to develop a cron job in `Ubuntu` using `R` with it `cronR` package. That job would run on the first Sunday of every 3 months (this 3 should be a variable). However the `cronR` package does not give any such functionality (as far as I know).

Can anyone give some pointer if it is possible to achieve this using `cronR` package, or by any other means?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with the semantics of basic Unix `cron`.  At least not *as is*.

What you *can* do, easily, is to have `cron` call a script daily which then

- open a small 'state' memory file, can be csv or maybe easiest rds
- based on the last state, and current date and time, decide whether to run
- if it runs, update the 'state' file